# Hibernate (2.1) - join tables by two columns

Tags: hibernate

Is there any solution in Hibernate xml mapping to join tables (T1,T2) by two columns (colC, colD) ?
e.g

```
T1
cols: id...colC,colD

T2
cols: id...colC,colD
```

(which means just: ... where t1.colC=t2.colC and t1.colD=t2.colD)
Thanks in advance.

Env:
Hibernate 2.1

Comment: Why dont you use HQL or Criteira for fetching the data form the Hibernate session?

Comment: Getting the Hibernate session is protected

Answer (score 0):

We made a view to join them together, it seems to be good enough. I also really miss the HQL access ...